# Fast Pythonic way to convert ByteArray to string with in-place substitutions

Tags: python, python-3.x, performance

Please consider the following code.  The purpose here is to create a typical ascii dump of binary data, substituting non-printable characters with `'.'`.

Both segments of code print the same output.  The second seems more "Pythonic", but is (in my measurements) 2-3 times slower than the first, presumably because it creates more temporary objects.

Since I'm going to be doing this many millions of times, performance matters.  Is there a faster Pythonic way to do this?

```
ba = bytearray.fromhex("01610262") # non-printable binary data, 'a', binary, 'b'
for i in range(len(ba)):
    if not chr(ba[i]).isprintable():
        ba[i] =  ord('.')
text = ba.decode("ascii")
print(text)  # prints ".a.b"

ba = bytearray.fromhex("01610262")
text = bytes(map(lambda b: ord('.') if not chr(b).isprintable() else b, ba)).decode("ascii")
print(text)  # prints ".a.b"
```

Version with performance measurement:

```
ITERATIONS=1000000

start = time.time()
for z in range(ITERATIONS):
    ba = bytearray.fromhex("01610262")
    for i in range(0, len(ba)):
        if not chr(ba[i]).isprintable():
            ba[i] =  ord('.')
    text = ba.decode("ascii")
    #print(text)
end = time.time()
print("first elapsed time:", (end-start))

start = time.time()
for z in range(ITERATIONS):
    ba = bytearray.fromhex("01610262")
    text = bytes(map(lambda b: ord('.') if not chr(b).isprintable() else b, ba)).decode("ascii")
    #print(text)
end = time.time()
print("second elapsed time:", (end-start))
```

Outputs:

```
first elapsed time: 2.4349358081817627
second elapsed time: 5.805044889450073
```

UPDATE:
Discovered that running the timing test from the command line, instead of my IDE (which was attaching a debugger) both increased the performance, and radically reduced the performance differential.

The accepted answer (using a translation table) is by far fastest when run from the command line.

Marat's ''.join() solution in the comments falls between the first & second options above when run from command line (but is much worse under my debugger [using Visual Studio Code Python Extensions].)

Comment: `timeit` shows a lot less dramatic difference between these approaches, 735ns vs 864ns. The difference might be because of how variables are allocated and not the method efficiency

Comment: `''.join(chr(b) if b < 127 else '.' for b in ba)` is only slightly faster (645ns), but definitely more readable

Comment: could you create the lambda function outside the `map` function. That will improve the speed

Comment: @Marat - thanks for the join suggestion.  In my tests it fell between by first & second in timing - when running from the command.  When running in my IDE (which attaches a debugger), it's a full order of magnitude slower.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can be bothered setting up a translation table then I got much better results using that method on your example.

```
btrans = bytes.maketrans(b'\x01\x02',b'..')
for z in range(ITERATIONS):
    ba = bytearray.fromhex("01610262")
    text = ba.translate(btrans).decode('ascii')
    #print(text)
end = time.time()
print("third elapsed time:", (end-start))

first elapsed time: 1.4424219131469727
second elapsed time: 1.1425127983093262
third elapsed time: 0.3709402084350586
```

Comment: Setting up a translation table was well worth the perf gain. Thanks! @jonathan